# IndexError: list index out of range stair algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, nested-loops, index-error

I want to make an algorithm that counts how many stairs can guy jump from each stair. b is his jump height and c is height of each stair.

```
b = 7
c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
indx = 1
indx1 = 1

for x in c:
    while x < b:
        if x + c[indx] < b:
            x = x + c[indx]
            indx += 1
            print(x)
        else:
            indx1 += 1
            indx = indx1
```

This code gives me this output:
    3
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    6
      File "file location*", line 9, in 
        if x + c[indx] < b:
    IndexError: list index out of range

I don't know why it doesn't skip that if and doesn't go to the else statement...

Comment: try to add `print(indx)` right before `c[indx]` and try to follow how this happens (or better yet, use a proper debugger to see it step by step).

Comment: add if to check index add continue for skip and stop when is success

Comment: Your "suggested solution" does not make any sense. If `c[indx]` causes an `IndexError`, then it is guaranteed that `c[indx + 1]` will do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need make variable to hold threshold checker loop like this code:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":

  b = 7
  c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
  indx = 0
  indx1 = 0

  stop = 0

  for x in c:
    while stop < b:
       result = x + c[indx]
       print("check jump {}".format(result))

       if result < b:
         x = result
         indx += 1
         print("jump {}".format(x))

       else:
         indx1 += 1
         indx = indx1
         print("not jump {}".format(indx))

       stop = stop + indx
```

I put a variable result is value after compute loop index for in. I hope that it would help you

Answer (score 2):

It's crashing because your while loop is checking whether `x < b`. b is 7, and everything in `c` is less than 7, so it checks the whole array. `indx` starts from 1 (rather than 0) and increments every time you go around, so on the last element it is one larger than the largest index in the array, and you get the error you're seeing.

You need to do one of the following:

- Change the loop guard on your while loop so that it stops before it runs off the array
- Check whether `indx` is too large before running it in that if statement
- Start `indx` with a value of 0, not 1
- Take one off `indx` when using it as an index into the list

Take your pick.

Comment: that's right, in python index is started from 0, not 1

Comment: I know that it start from 0 but I want to add the height of the next stair not the current one. That's why I started from 1.

Comment: OK, then you need to make sure you don't run the check on the last stair. If there is no next stair then you can't check its height!